# How to upload App Bundle to the Play Store while opting out of signing?

Tags: android, google-chrome, apk, progressive-web-apps, pwabuilder

I am attempting to use https://pwabuilder.com to generate an Android App Bundle for my website and upload it to the Google Play Store.

I have been following the instructions listed here exactly: https://github.com/pwa-builder/CloudAPK/blob/master/Next-steps.md

I believe step 3 may be inaccurate or out of date because the Google Play prompt includes this:

[image]

Step 3 in the tutorial is telling me to "Opt out" and then upload the `aab` bundle, but Google says by opting out you will not be able to upload an `aab` file.

And sure enough, when I select "Opt out" and attempt to upload my app's `aab` file, I receive the following error:

> To upload an Android App Bundle you must be enrolled in App Signing by
> Google Play.

How can I correct this? Should I upload an apk instead? Should I select a different option? Something else?

Here are the other options:

[image]

Comment: I think you summarised it pretty well already: if you want to upload an AAB you need to enroll in Play Signing; if you don't want to enroll in Play Signing for whatever reason, then you'll need to upload an APK. Now that from August 2020, new apps will only be able to upload AABs.